# How to include help '?' in title bar of winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add a help '?' button to the title bar (along with minimize, maximize, and close buttons) of my winforms application (C#.NET 2.0). I have tried using the Help Button property of Form, but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Both answers are faulty.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The Help icon is only there when HelpButton = True and MaximizeBox and MimizeBox are both set to False. This is the windows standard. If you really want to go beyond and add a button anyway, you'll have to customize the titlebar.

This is not an easy task, it either involves many hooks, or a complete redesign of the title bar.

Are you sure you want to depart from the Windows standard? Wouldn't it be better to have Help available in the menu or on a toolbar somewhere?

Comment: Thanks. Now I know the reason why HelpButton property is not working, as I have my MinimizeBox = true. I don't think I would prefer to depart from Windows standard. I would rather add a help button on the form. Regards.

Comment: Any idea *why* both are not allowed?

Comment: MaximizeBox and MimizeBox are both set to False. That's intuitive. +1 from me

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the solution you must change FormBorderStyle to FixedDialog. To benefit help functionality use _HelpButtonClicked event in form.

Comment: This is what I was missing, none of the other posts seemed to mention this part...