# Add help button, but keep maximize and minimize

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to be able to add the help button onto my winform, but keep the maxmimize and minimize buttons, but windows standard is to disable both to be able to show the help button.

There is already a question similar:
[How to include help '?' in title bar of winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474663/how-to-include-help-in-title-bar-of-winform) - 
but in that question the one who asked the question is content with removing those 2 buttons for the help to show.

Is there away that i can have help, max, min and close buttons all there at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but did you read that answer?  It hints that you would have to recreate the title bar yourself.  That's a lot of work for such little gain.

Comment: @LarsTech - I was hoping there was a way without completely recoding the border.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows doesn't support showing both.  A workaround is to provide your own button to trigger the same action.  Put it somewhere close to the upper right corner.  You trigger this by sending yourself a WM_SYSCOMMAND message, just like the standard help button does.  Like this:

```
    private void Help_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Help.Capture = false;
        SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_CONTEXTHELP, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
    private const int SC_CONTEXTHELP = 0xf180;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
```

Which assumes that button's name is "Help".

Comment: I did not realize i could use a button i create to trigger the same action. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it looks like windows does support showing both, as you can see by opening the latest version of Word. In fact, they even put another button in there for ribbon control. It's just that for some reason, this is not properly supported in Windows Forms...

Comment: Office apps use a custom frame, not the standard Windows window frame.  Nice things you can do when you have hundreds of programmers working on a product.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to draw your own border.

```
FormBorderStyle = None
```

Now construct your own caption area.  This is non trivial because you have to handle drag resize events, transparency if you want rounded corners, etc.