# How to create small help - about button in order to show the application version

Tags: c#, winforms

i have Winform application and i want to add the small help button with about option to show my application version number (i am using Application.ProductVersion), how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to activate the help button go to your Form properties. 
Set MaximizeBox and MinimizeBox to false and HelpButton to true.
This will display the Help button. 
Then go to the events for the form and double click HelpButtonClicked. 
In this function you place whatever code you use to display your version number.

I would also recommend you to use: 
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()

Comment: and if i want the option to minimize my application ?

Comment: If you want to be able to minimize the application you need to add the button yourself. There is another stack overflow thread about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140090/add-help-button-but-keep-maximize-and-minimize

Comment: The system.reflection line just provides you with your application version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version