# Add buttons to Caption Bar Form / Help button

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

Is there any way to add custom buttons to form (similar to shown on the picture below)?
I googled a lot and all code samples I found were written for Windows XP - and didnt work in Windows 10

Even adding help button would work in majority cases to me but this requires min/max buttons to be disabled (but I need them)

Tried eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140090/add-help-button-but-keep-maximize-and-minimize) but doesnt wotk to me.

```
HelpButton = True 
MaximizeBox = False 
MimizeBox =False
```

I have also searched for some free or not free components - found only few, but only id you buy entire components package (so no worth cost/money in this case)

[image]

Comment: Did you consider implementing your own form top bar?

Comment: I know i can make borderless form add own panel and simulate form that way. But it is a lot coding Im checking somethinf easier for naow (also I need to migrate hundreds of forms to that, so preferably Id like something where i just change class from Form to FormExtended or so...)

Comment: Dwm renders the non-client areas of the windows. Thus, you cannot add a button or something else unless you remove the Dwm-rendered non-client area and draw your own non-client area.

Comment: Thanks for tip. never heard about DWM... Do you mean I should be able to archive that by something like this ?


https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/dwm/customframe?redirectedfrom=MSDN